# Disable autofilling missing HTML closing tags in Reveal MD

Tags: markdown, reveal.js

The following code:

````
```python
x = '<x>'
```
````

Evaluates in Reveal MD to:

```
x = '<x>'</x>
```

Reveal MD tries to explore HTML tags and in case  of missing closing tags found it closes them automatically. Is there any way to block this feature? This is obviously a bug - I specified after backticks that my intention was to put Python code, not HTML one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<` and `>` of the "tag" with html encoding items.

Expression

````
```python
x = '&lt;x&gt;'
```
````

evaluates to

```
x = '<x>'
```

as expected.